# Wordpress the_content issue

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Os3.png)

Hello,

I'm trying to solve this problem in Wordpress. I need to have my permalink structures as post names, so making them plain is not an option even if it fixes this problem (it generates others).

As I've seen:
I need to put  into the file manager, because I can't access and edit my page using elementor.

Now I have tried to change the php for different reasons the last days, like colors etc., but always, like now, I can save my changes but nothing changes at all.. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Marc White

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

according to me there is something wrong with your data. As some github like pass custom php function to solve this error.
Github link for the related issue- [Link](https://github.com/dudaster/ele-custom-skin/issues/201)

If you still face issue just lemme. I think will help you.